# Why does the Laplace transform of a function in L2 belong in the Hardy space?

Tags: lp-spaces, laplace-transform, hardy-spaces

Does anyone have a proof / mathematical explanation to why the Laplace transform of a function of $\mathbb{L}^2(0,\infty )$ belongs to the Hardy space?

Any guidance would be fantastic! I cant find anything clear online that makes sense to me
.

Comment: Are you sure that this claim is true? Where did you find this claim?

Comment: K. Hoffman, ‘‘Banach Spaces of Analytic Functions,’’ Dover, New York, 1962    
You can find this here:  
 https://ia903400.us.archive.org/22/items/banachspacesofan032699mbp/banachspacesofan032699mbp.pdf on page 122. They state using the Paley Wiener theorem but omit the details

Comment: Perhaps take a look at [this note](http://www1.maths.leeds.ac.uk/~pmt6jrp/MAGIC082notes.pdf)